Problem in MySql query on Wordpress
According to https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/
I'm trying to retrieve a value in a WP table with a simple query
<?php
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT user_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}prflxtrflds_user_field_data WHERE id = 37" );
echo $results;

But $result is an empty array value. If I execute query for example in phpmyadmin I obtain the right value. I'm using a plugin to execute code in WP page.
Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? Thank you very much for any suggestion

Can you turn on database error output and try again? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/#show-and-hide-sql-errors

Thanks for the answer. error output is : Errore sul database di WordPress: []

@giulio64 are you sure the array is empty? Perhaps you're just seeing a "Array" printed on screen? If so, then try using var_dump() instead - var_dump( $results ); ..

I solved it.
The problem is that the query I need returns only one value at a time, so I have to use $wpdb->get_var( "QUERY...') instead of $wpdb->get_results( "QUERY...'). Thanks anyway

True, depending on what's unique in your table, but get_results() still should have returned you an array of a result with a single value.

@giulio64, Rup is right, and what I was telling you is that you can't simply echo an array, i.e. with your code, echo $results; would output Array. So basically, you could have used something like echo $results[0]->user_id;, but yes, get_var() would be easier for you.

I think the problem is here
{$wpdb->prefix}prflxtrflds_user_field_data
It seems your {$wpdb->prefix} value is prflxtrflds
So you can directly use :
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT user_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}user_field_data WHERE id = 37" );`

